# Facebook graph API 'ids' variable limit

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-batch-request

I'm making API calls to retrieve simple data from Facebook pages:

```
/[page_id]?fields=likes,talking_about_count,checkins
```

I know I can get multiple results by providing multiple ids using the 'ids' variable:

```
/?ids=[page_id],[page_id],[page_id]&fields=likes,talking_about_count,checkins
```

My problem is that I don't how many ids I can retrieve simultaneously. I know the limit for batched request is 50, but I can't find the documentation for the 'ids' variable.

---

**UPDATE:** it seems like this limit has been removed on version 2.0 of the graph API, but I am still looking for an official answer.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I used Graph Explorer to list all post ids on a page. It returned me 140 posts.
I then sent those 140 posts to the Graph API using the `ids` parameter and got this in return:

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "(#100) Too many IDs. Maximum: 50. Provided: 140.", 
    "type": "OAuthException", 
    "code": 100
  }
}
```

So the answer is currently 50.

[Facebook Graph API Limit Documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/making-multiple-requests#limits)

Comment: Not documented anywhere, 50 appears to still be the limit